# Why is the program not working correctly?

Tags: python

I'm doing a project for school and one of the tasks is to create a program that will tell the user how long it took them to type in the alphabet correctly.

It always says "Try again" no matter if the input is correct or not; I'm not really sure what I did wrong.

I'd much appreciate if someone could help me tackle this problem.

```
def game():
    import time

    start_time=time.time()
    alphabet = input("Type in the aphabet :  ")
    alphabet = alphabet.capitalize()

    if alphabet == "A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z":
        print("Well done.")
        end_time=time.time()-start_time
        print("It took you :{0:.2f}".format(end_time),"seconds.")
    elif alphabet == "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
        print("Well done.")
        end_time=time.time()-start_time
        print("It took you :{0:.2f}".format(end_time),"seconds.")
    else:
        print("Try again....")
        game()
    print()

    again = input("Do you want to try again? Y or N ")
    again = again.capitalize()
    if again == "Y":
        game()
    elif again == "N":
        print("Goodbye.") 
    else:
        print("Try again...")
        game()
game()
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stack Overflow. You may want to read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then [edit] yours to make it fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please don't use images to share the code.

Comment: Did you try printing the results of the `capitalize` method? [It doesn't do what you think it does.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize)

Comment: I recommend you, delete this post and then try post a new, with code in text

Answer (score 2):

Str.capitalize only capitalises the first letter not the whole word. You want str.upper()

Comment: Thank you. I changed it and it works now.